# need help to shorten mysql multiple OR conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains manager id and staff ids (comma separated) and i have the following sql statement:

```
SELECT manager_id, staff_ids
FROM manager_staffs 
WHERE 1 IN (staff_ids)
OR 3 IN (staff_ids)
OR 5 IN (staff_ids)
OR 23 IN (staff_ids)
OR 12 IN (staff_ids)
OR 16 IN (staff_ids)
OR 19 IN (staff_ids)
OR 32 IN (staff_ids)
OR 123 IN (staff_ids)
............
```

basically, it is a very long query with a lot of 'OR' condition. I would like to improve or shorten it if there is a way.

need help from all the sql gurus.

Comment: Is staff_ids a field containing a comma separated list of staff ids? If so your query would not appear to work, except when the manager has a single member of staff. If it is a comma separated list then you should split the list up and onto another table, with one row per member of staff on that new table

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your data structure - don't put all the staff ids in one column. Make a table - you can call it manager_staff:

```
CREATE TABLE manager_staff (
     manager_id int,
     staff_id int
);
```

And so you can make records that show which manager every staff person reports to. Then your query becomes:

```
select manager_id, staff_id from manager_staff where staff_id in (1,3,...);
```

Comment: sigh. sorry. i wish i could change.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try this

```
    SELECT manager_id, staff_ids
   FROM manager_staffs 
    WHERE staff_ids IN (1,3,5,23,12,16,19,32,123,.......)
```

- you have no choice how to reduce your `OR`s only if you create other table and select them like query above.
- structure your table is best to get performance when retrieving data.

your table should look like that

```
 manager_staff 
 manager_id , staff_id
   1            1
   1            3
   1            5
   1            23
   ..........
```

Comment: I dont think this will work. accoding to him staff_ids are in comma separated

Comment: Yeah. They are comma separated.

Comment: its your structure wrong you should created other table with staff_ids and then you get them by my query

Comment: sorry, table structure cannot be changed. it's been there for so many years and there are so many pages using that table.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what are you trying to achieve but try this:

> SELECT manager_id, staff_ids
>   FROM manager_staffs 
>   WHERE staff_ids in ('1','3' and so on)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming staff_ids is a comma separated field then you could do the following.

```
SELECT DISTINCT manager_id, staff_ids
FROM manager_staffs a
INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 AS staff_id UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 23 UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 16 UNION SELECT 19 UNION SELECT 32 UNION SELECT 123) b
ON FIND_IN_SET(b.staff_id, a.staff_ids) > 0
```

But as I commented earlier, splitting it up would be a far better idea